# Native base flex direction on Content not working

Tags: ios, react-native, native-base

I want to display two images side by side instead of on in the bottom of another. Here is my code :

```
 <Content style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
     <Image
        key={data[0]['id']}
         source={{ uri: data[0]['image']['url']}}
         style={{
           width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.2,
           height: 120,
           }}
      />
     <Image
       key={data[1]['id']}
       source={{ uri: data[1]['image']['url']}}
       style={{
         width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.2,
         height: 120,
         }}
     />           
 </Content>
```

But it is not working as it should. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Avoid flexWrap and use flex.

<Content style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex:1}}> // Note flex.
  <Image
     key={data[0]['id']}
     source={{ uri: data[0]['image']['url']}}
     style={{
       flex: 0.5, // Give the 50% of the width to this image.
       height: 120,
       }}
   />
  <Image
    key={data[1]['id']}
    source={{ uri: data[1]['image']['url']}}
    style={{
      flex: 0.5, // Give the 50% of the width to this image.
      height: 120,
     }}
 />
```

```
I haven't really tested this code. But it should work fine. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary** Solved by using **View** instead of **Content**. But the issues remains with Native-Base Content.

Comment: The replacing component for NativeBase Content is, React Native Keyboard Aware Scroll View's `KeyboardAwareScrollView`